# How to create DataFrame schema from schema json file in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to use Pyspark to create DataFrame schema from schema json file. Once DataFrame schema created, I will load json data files by using this schema. Could somebody help me?  Thanks in advance. For my schema json file look like below:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "visitorId",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "visitStartTime",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "totals",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "visits",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "hits",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "pageviews",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "transactions",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "timeOnScreen",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "channelGrouping",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is not defined as expected and pyspark cannot parse it.

I've changed your schema to:

```json
{
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "visitorId",
            "type": "integer",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "visitStartTime",
            "type": "integer",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "totals",
            "type": {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "visits",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "nullable": true,
                        "metadata": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "hits",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "nullable": true,
                        "metadata": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "pageviews",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "nullable": true,
                        "metadata": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "transactions",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "nullable": true,
                        "metadata": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "timeOnScreen",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "nullable": true,
                        "metadata": {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "channelGrouping",
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Saved that as `schema.json` file and then created a `StructType` from this json using:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Test") \
        .getOrCreate()

    with open("schema.json") as f_in:
        schema_data = json.load(f_in)

    data = {}
    schemaFromJson = StructType.fromJson(schema_data)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schemaFromJson)
    df.printSchema()
```

The result is:

```
root
 |-- visitorId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- visitStartTime: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- totals: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visits: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hits: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pageviews: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- transactions: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timeOnScreen: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- channelGrouping: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion is much helpful for me.

Comment: @uugrite You're welcome! If you think that my example answered your question, accept it. Otherwise include more information.